# Access to files in a folder in silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight

I add a folder of image files in my silverlight application. I want to put name of these files (jpg file) to arraylist.
How can I access to these files in silverlight 3?

---

Comment: Where is the folder in relation to your xap file?

Comment: We need more information to help with this.  Are you talking about image files that will be deployed as part of your Silverlight package, image files in a directory on your web server, or files in a folder on the client machine (which is not directly possible in SL)?

Comment: thanks for your answers.
image files are in a folder in my silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the openFileDialog class if you are accessing files on your server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

This gives a good intro to how it works. You're going to have to write the logic of changing the stream into a BitmapImage. But that only 3 lines of code. I'll supply it if you want it.

However if you just want to access images within the application all you need to do is accesses them within the application by creating them as a new bitmapimage:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitMapImage(new Uri("imagesFolder/yourImageName.jpg",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
//set the height and width properties afterwards
```